# change .popover-user-notifications style Don't work?

Tags: jquery, whmcs

This code doesn't seem to work!

```
$(function()$('.popover-user-notifications').attr('style','left:1194'));
```

I want to change the left value of this div style!

```
<div class="popover popover-user-notifications fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover104120" style="top: 93px; left: 1593px; display: block;"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCYiK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The curly brackets `{` and `}` are missing. Those are needed to wrap a function.

Try:

```
$(function(){$('.popover-user-notifications').attr('style','left:1194')});
```

And I would suggest using the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method instead of changing the style attribute:

```
$(function(){$('.popover-user-notifications').css('left','1194')});
```

Comment: I want to change change style value. What should I do?.

Comment: because <div class="popover popover-user-notifications fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover104120" style="top: 93px; left: 1593px; display: block;">   Internal style, high priority !

Comment: The jQuery `.css()` method does change the style of the matched element... Try the second option and tell me if it works. If not, tell me if you have errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: No errors!
But the location of the div has not changed!

Comment: Ok I see. That popover is the result of a tooltip plugin? Tell me which plugin please.

Comment: Would this be a [Bootstrap popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)?